# Issue with encoding of cyrlic character strings

Tags: r, encoding

I have some cyrlic strings in my dataframe that I can't manage to read acuratelly.

This is how the dataframe looks after I load the csv:

```
unique(transactions$orders)
 [1] "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ30Å" "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ30Å"  "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ30Å" "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ50Å" "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ50Å" "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ53Å" "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ53Å" 
 [8] "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ53Å" "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ30"   "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ30"  "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ30"  "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ50"  "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ10"   "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ50" 
[15] "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ40"   "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ53"  "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ53"   "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ53"  "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ10"  "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ30Ï"  "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ50Ï"
[22] "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ30Ï" "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ30Ï" "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ50Ï" "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ50"   "ÌÈÏÑ-ÏÏ10"  "ÊÈÁÑ-ÏÏ53Ï" "ÈÍÒ-ÏÏ53Ï"
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide some more details on how you have tried to read your data - which function, etc. You might try different encodings in your reading function, e.g., "UTF-8", "latin1", etc. Specifying the encoding that matches your file format should do it. Also, you might try different reading functions from different packages (e.g. `xlsx`, `stringr`, etc.). In special cases like yours, some might produce better results than others.

Comment: Also please report the output of `sessionInfo()`. The solution to this problem likely depends on your platform (Win/Mac/Linux) and your locale.